# How to get synchronous SerialPort Read in NodeJS

Tags: node.js, express, arduino, node-serialport

Actually working on an automaton project (based on Arduino <-> Serial <-> Raspberry), I seem to be kind of stuck on the serial interface.

Basically, I'm using Express to read/write on some parameter on the arduino by URL in that kind of syntax (http://localhost:3000/parameter/6 or http://localhost:3000/parameter/6/set?value=10).

Since I'm willing to get a simple/short result (as an API), I decided to render a simple json object on each request, there is also **no way for me to use post-rendering scripts/frameworks like `Socket.io`/`jQuery`/... for this purpose** (I'd probably often call those URLs from `curl`/`wget`/[other html parsers]).

Now the thing is that there is no problem to write on the port, but for the reading, I'd like to **wait for the buffer to be returned from `serialport.on('data', function(buffer) { ... })` before rendering the page**.

As `serialport.on('data', ... )` does seem to be called only once per request, the only way I found for the moment is to redirect to the same page until the buffer has been read, which seem kind of a **nasty way of getting things done**, also it is incomplete ...

**Here's a bit of code to get an idea of the actual logic :**

**Library :**

```
// -> lib/serial.js - LIBRARY
var SerialPort = require("serialport");
var data = {'state': 0};


var serialPort = new SerialPort(port, {
  baudrate: 115200,
  parser: SerialPort.parsers.readline('\r\n'),
});

serialPort.on('open', function() {
  console.log('Serial port Open');
  serialPort.on('data', function(buffer) { data.buffer = buffer, data.state = 1 });
});

function readConfig(cmd, paramNb) {
  var cmd = String.fromCharCode(cmd);
  var param = String.fromCharCode(paramNb);
  if (serialPort.isOpen() == true) {
    serialPort.write(cmd + param + '\n', function(err) {
      if (err) {
        return console.log('Error on write: ', err.message);
      }
      console.log('message written');
    });
  }
  return data;
};

function writeConfig(cmd, paramNb, value) {
  var cmd = String.fromCharCode(cmd);
  var param = String.fromCharCode(paramNb);
  var value = String.fromCharCode(value);
  if (serialPort.isOpen() == true) {
    serialPort.write(cmd + param + value + '\n', function(err) {
      if (err) {
        return console.log('Error on write: ', err.message);
      }
      console.log('message written');
    });
  }
};

exports.readConfig = readConfig;
exports.writeConfig = writeConfig;
```

**Route :**

```
// -> parameter.js - ROUTE
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var serial = require('../../lib/serial');
var sleep = require('sleep');

/* SET Parameter. */
router.get('/:id/set', function(req, res) {
  var id = req.params.id;
  var value = req.query.value;
  serial.writeConfig('b', id, value);
  res.json({'result': value, 'id': id});
});

/* GET Parameter. */
router.get('/:id', function(req, res) {
  var id = req.params.id;
  var buffer = serial.readConfig('a', id);
  if (buffer.state != 0) {
    res.json({'result': buffer});
  }
  else {
    sleep.usleep(100000);
    res.redirect('/api/parameter/' + id);       // <- Nasty Bulls**t
  }
});

module.exports = router;
```

The first idea I came up with was to find a synchronous way to read the port so I can call something like this (pseudo-code) :

```
while (buffer == '') { var buffer = serial.read; }
res.json({buffer});
```

Anyway thanks everyone.

Comment: You need to change the readConfig function to take callback as the 3rd argument and call it after you get the data. So below `var data = {'state': 0};` add `var callback = null;` add it to `function readConfig(and, paramNb, cb){ callback = cb; ....}` and when you get data in `serialPort.on('data'` call it `callback(buffer);`. Then use it in the route `serial.readConfig('a', is, function(data){ res.json({result: data});`

Comment: Finally I managed to get it right by following your example.